# input javascript checked - unchecked

Tags: javascript, input, checked, unchecked

I have input in body of my html page:

```
<input id="showElement" type="checkbox" checked="checked" oninput="onShowElementChange()" checked="checked"/>
```

And in script there is:

```
  function onShowElementChange(value) {
  scene3dManager.showElement = $('#showElement').is(':checked')
}

function onShowElementChange(value) {
  scene3dManager.showElement = $('#showElement').is(':checked')
}

<input id="showElement" type="checkbox" checked="checked" oninput="onShowElementChange()" checked="checked" />
```

But, for some reason, it doesn't work ... My input should be clicked by default, and user can unclick it if he chooses to.

Perhaps, there is some mistake in my code, so, im asking for help. Thanks

Comment: two 'checked="checked"' in the tag?

Comment: Not sure how it works in js ...that should say to input to be checked by default...perhaps that is my mistake and that it should be done in some other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checked without the value checked should work fine.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked/>
```

Below should work if you remove `oninput="onShowSeabedChange()"`

```
$("#showSeabed").on("click", function(){
   scene3dManager.showSeabed = $('#showSeabed').is(':checked');
});
```

Comment: so no oninput in input tag, and in scrypt goes $("#showSeabed")..etc? Am I right... That should make input checked by default and able to uncheck/check...

Comment: `$("#showSeabed").on("click", function(){
   scene3dManager.showSeabed = this.checked;
});`

Comment: Removing `="checked"` part from the tag should give you pre-checked checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

`oninput` event will not work in checkbox or radio use onchange event.

```
<input id="showElement" type="checkbox" onchange="onShowElementChange()" checked="checked"/>
```

And you can also try like below will work.

```
<input id="showElement" type="checkbox" onchange="onShowElementChange(this.checked)" checked="checked"/>
```

JavaScript

```
function onShowElementChange(checked) {
  console.log(checked);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ...lucky for me, I do have some inputs with range and there it will work fine, but I should change it on checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

I think that checked="checked" is deprecated, try just checked instead

```
<input id="showElement" type="checkbox" oninput="onShowElementChange()" checked/>
```